# Should truly fresh steak (i. e. still purple) have a smell?

Tags: food-safety, beef, steak, fresh

I recently purchased a strip steak from my local grocery.  Got home and noticed that the other side (the side that was face down at the deli) had a section that was noticeably purple.  If I get really close, there is definitely a smell, but it's not a great smell.  I've smelled oxidized (brown) beef before and find it has kind of a "sweet" smell, but this is not that.

My first thought was that I was sold spoiled steak.  Then I cut the steak in half and noticed that the inside of the steak was the same color and had the same smell.  I don't think steak spoils from the inside out, so now I don't know.

For what it's worth, it's the smell that's got me concerned.  There's no other signs of spoilage that I can find--the steak isn't sticky or slimy.

Can anyone provide some expert advice on this?  I'm inclined to think it's fine and is just really, REALLY fresh, but I'm hoping someone else knows what's going on.

Comment: Without looking at it I doubt anyone will be able to provide satisfactory answers. Could post some photos we can look at?

Comment: I ate the steak anyway.  If I still feel okay tomorrow, I'll answer my own question.

Comment: Let us know if you develop any super powers or other benign side effects in the meantime. Also where we can get this purple steak, you know, "just for scientific reasons" and all.

Comment: Not posting as an answer because there's no way to know for sure, but perhaps you got hold of a piece of 'dark cutting beef'. An excellent article on the subject can be found here: http://chicolockersausage.com/2013/11/06/did-you-know-there-is-such-a-thing-as-purple-meat/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ate the steak and was fine.  I think it was just an non-oxidized portion of steak.  I let it sit in the refrigerator for an hour or so before it I ate it and it's color changed from purple to red, so I'm inclined to think oxidation.